# MVC6 routing to single-page application without losing 404

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, angular2-routing

I'm writing a single-page application with angular2 and MVC5. I'm new to both, though, and I'm having trouble with the routing.

I'd like to match URLs as:

- `/`  ->  go to my index page, which bootstraps angular
- `/api/{controller}/{id?}` -> REST API
- `/{*anythingelse}` -> if a file exists there, return it as static content; otherwise if angular can route it, have angular route it; otherwise return 404.

The second point's easy enough, and I can get the client-side routing working if I'm willing to give up 404 returns, but I can't seem to reconcile it all.

It seems like this ought to work:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "api",
        template: "api/{controller}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "spa",
        template: "{*anythingelse}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

and:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: "/", name: 'Splash', component: SplashView },
    { path: '/accounts/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginView },
    { path: '/accounts/register', name: 'Registration', component: RegistrationView },
    { path: '/home/...', name: 'Home', component: HomeView },
])
```

But that just serves Index.cshtml for every request that isn't a static file.

I feel like this must already be a solved problem, but I haven't been able to find anything online about it. How does one do this properly?

I'm using "HTML5"-style paths rather than hash-style.

Comment: Is your REST api using WebApi? WebApi is a separate framework from MVC and has its own separate route configuration. If using MVC (not WebApi), you don't have it configured right - you need to provide a default action `defaults: new { action = "Index" }` or an action in the URL `api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}`.

Comment: Also, your assumption about route order is impossible. Angular runs in the browser, so it will route first. Otherwise it will attempt the routes you have configured in the exact order you configure them in on the server side. Once the request hits the server, you can't give control back to Angular again.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I put down MVC5 but actually meant MVC6 on ASP.NET 5. In ASP.NET 5 the WebAPI and MVC routers have been merged.

Comment: From-Angular navigation shouldn't be a problem, since I'd only provide navigation to pages that exist and thus don't need a 404. I'm mainly looking at the case where the user enters a URI directly. There the server gets the first crack at it, and could return a 404 if it knew which URIs the client will accept. Maybe I can tell the server that via tooling in some way.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two ways to go about doing it.  If you are using the HashLocationStrategy I would strongly encourage you to do this on your server side implementation as I have found it much easier to deal with.

Otherwise you could make your own RouterOutlet component that handled the exceptions.  I am not 100% clear on how you could get it to work with your RouterConfig as I have not delved that deep into the routing aspect, but I bet you could see if there exists a route then go there otherwise 404 error.  Here is my code that deals with seeing if a user is logged in with Json Web tokens.

```
import {Directive, Attribute, ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';

@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
  publicRoutes: any;
  private parentRouter: Router;

  constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
              _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string) {
    super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);

    this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;

  }

  activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {

    if (!localStorage.getItem('jwt') || !tokenNotExpired('jwt')) {//Public Routes does not work with Hash Location Strategy, need to come up with something else.
      // todo: redirect to Login, may be there is a better way?
      if(localStorage.getItem('jwt')){
        localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
      }
      this.parentRouter.navigate(['Login']);
    }
    return super.activate(instruction);
  }
}
```

As you can see I handle my checking for the Token, and if they don't have a token they can only go to my login page.  Then in your app.component or  your bootstrapped component just use this as your router-outlet instead of the original.

Sorry I can't be more helpful but I hope this gets you pointed in the right direction!

Comment: Perhaps I'm simply being dense, but I don't follow how you're getting from an overridden RouterOutlet (client-side) to a 404 (server-side).

Comment: So what I was trying to show you is you could handle a `if does not exist in RouterConfig route 404` with the same kind of functionality, because for every url that gets received will pass through your new router-outlet and do a check.

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about a not-found page that just _says_ "404"? I'm looking for an actual 404 HTTP response code from the web server.

Comment: Oh ok.  I would maybe look at Angular2's serverside rendering.  I have not delved very deep into it, but you could just handle the 404 server-side and then send it to angular.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a regex route constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute("app", "{*anything}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }, 
    new {anything = new RegexRouteConstraint("^(?!api\\/).+") });
```

This will prevent your catch all route from mapping to any request that begins with "api/"